# Smoking Transistor in Low-Side Switch. What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: transistors, switches, power-dissipation

I have some of [these](http://ledfactorymart.com/rgb-al-140mm.html) (RGB LEDs with drivers). They connect to 12V, and they draw a max of 1.8A total (full white):

[image: Load]

I wanted to add a low-side switch to turn the load on/off via a PIC I/O pin output. After getting some advice in [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192747/how-do-i-find-the-output-voltage-of-a-load), I created the circuit below:

[image: switch expected]

The values above are what I expected the switch to behave like. According to the [TIP31C transistor datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP31C.pdf), Ic=1.8A gives a Vbe(sat) of 1.0V, and a Vce(sat) of 280mV, which apparently shouldn't get very hot:

[image: datasheet]

Instead, I'm seeing this:

[image: switch actual]

After a few seconds of being on, the transistor starts smoking and is way too hot to touch.

Can somebody please explain why there is a difference between what I expect to see and what I am seeing?

Note: my electronics knowledge is pretty basic, so please assume I don't know much, I won't be offended :). If I've left off any necessary information, please comment. Thanks!

Comment: Your transistor is hot because it is dissipating 4v *2A = 8watts. You need to increase the base current to drive the transistor into saturation and thereby reduce Vce. Try reducing the 100 Ohm base resistor to 47ohms and see if Vce reduces. If the PIC is not able to supply more current, use a second transistor and make a Darlington pair.

Comment: Your load must be lower in impedance than you expected. You thought it would draw 1.8 A with 11 V across it, but instead it is drawing 2.1 A with only 8 V across it. Since your load is demanding more current then you designed for, it's not surprising that the driving circuit is overheating.

Comment: More base current!

Comment: Even though smoking transistors is very satisfying, it can be very bad for you in the long run if you develop a lifelong habit.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you smoked a transistor. I did advise a small heatsink, just in case... I didn't get from your previous question enough details on what you intended to drive the transistor with (PIC). Also LEDs have highly variable resistance. It's not a constant with voltage! Your previous question didn't even say you wanted to drive LEDs. The LEDs you link to have no datasheet whatsoever. Measuring the current through LEDs at 12V is no guarantee for the current at 8V. See what @The Photon said.

Comment: Note that your planned 26mA base drive was at the limit [what PIC can generally provide](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m223028.aspx). Again you've included no details, even in this question about the specific PIC model, so don't know if it even supplied that current.

Comment: Also you've only planned for 0.8V Vbe (with that base current/resistor), even though I specifically wrote in my answer to your previous question "As for the transistor's base, you need to raise its potential to approximately 1.0V (at 2A load), not 0.8 as you have your schematic. (A bit more doesn't hurt.) Otherwise the transistor will not be fully saturated and will use more power as well as exhibit higher Vce than calculated above." You've basically only put the transistor in the active region, not in saturation. In the active region it dissipates way more power.

Comment: And this bit is perhaps confusing to you: what you may have read in general about a Vbe junction (or diode) drop being 0.7V is not accurate enough for power electronics and for power transistors in particular. The Vbe/junction drop can be more for these (at high currents, like in this example 1V Vbe at 2A collector current) that's why you need refer to the datasheet for a better estimation.

Comment: I do feel bad I didn't also emphasize that Ic/Ib (Hfe) is only 10 in saturation for this transistor (actually this is a very typical value for a power transistor)...  so the resulting base current (200mA) at 2A collector current is outside the realm of what you can directly drive with most MCU IO pins directly.

Comment: There are some MCUs, e.g. [iND80231](http://www.indiesemi.com/media/krankl-ProductBrief.pdf) that can source/sink 200mA on some of their IO pins, but these are specialty items.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: It is permitted for medicinal purposes, but only in states that are saturated.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: You're previous advice was very useful, and you can see from the first diagram in my post that I planned for 23mA from the PIC, a 1.0V Vbe, and 280mV Vce. The second diagram shows what I am actually seeing, which is 26mA, 0.8V Vbe, and 4.4V Vce. It seems like the Ic/Ib is the bit I was missing!

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: It was my fault for not mentioning I wanted to drive it from a PIC. I was just trying to keep the question concise, but I guess more details are better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll notice that in Figure 2 it states "Ic/Ib = 10".

This means that to saturate the transistor you should drive it as if the Hfe is only 10, not the almost 100 in Figure 1. Note also that figure 1 is the typical figure not the guaranteed value.  The guaranteed value in the data sheet is only 10 at 3A collector current.

You need to provide more base drive.

The PIC however will not be able to drive the required 180mA output. You need a darlington transistor such as a TIP120 or these days a better solution is to use a MOSFET. The TIP120 would have a saturated voltage drop of ~1V and so would require a heat sink. A mosfet would have a very low drop and would work without one.

Even there you have to be careful as many MOSFETs will require 10V drive, more than the PIC can provide.  For this there are so called Logic Level FETs that switch with only 5V on the gate.

Something like [FQP30N06L](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10213) would work.

Comment: Curses. You beat me to it.